# BIND plus Google Cloud DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am relatively new in DNS management and I want to ask what is the best way to go about this.

- We currently have our own Name Server as Authoritative ns1.ourcompany.com
- There are 5 other Name Servers configured, I assume for replication
- Those 5 name servers, plus ns1.ourcompany.com are the NS Entries in ENOM Registrar.

I copied the host entries using DNS Control (700+ records) and created the same zone in Google Cloud DNS.

QUESTION:
Can I add the GCP Name Servers to the list of NS in the registrar side? e.g Replace the `auth-ns1.tvc-ip.com` and `auth-ns2.tvc-ip.com` to `ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com` and `ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com`

Will these cause any issues?

The idea is to have the the GCP as another Name Server along with the current ones.

This is what the current BIND config looks like:

```
        @       IN      SOA     ns1.ourcompany.com. administrativecontact.ourcompany.com. (
                        2021010404    ; Serial
                        30m           ; Slave Server Refresh after 30 minutes
                        5m            ; Slave Server Retry after 5 minutes
                        4w            ; Slave Server Expire after 4 week
                        15m )         ; Default TTL of records 15 minutes
        ;
                IN      NS      Auth00.ns.colospace.com.
                IN      NS      Auth01.ns.colospace.com.
                IN      NS      Auth02.ns.colospace.com.
                IN      NS      ns1.ourcompany.com.
                IN      NS  auth-ns1.tvc-ip.com.    ; added rn 1-30-2015
                IN      NS  auth-ns2.tvc-ip.com.    ; added rn 1-30-2015de here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Either use what you already have or switch to Google Cloud DNS altogether.**

1. **DNS updates should be automated using *zone transfers*;** when ever you change a record on the primary name server (and update the *serial* in `SOA`), all the secondary name servers should automatically update this change.

   Because you cannot use Google Cloud DNS as a secondary this way, but you had to manually copy all the individual entries, you should not try and use it along with your current infrastructure.
2. **The `NS` entries for the zone must be *consistent*:**

   - between delegation and zone i.e. match with the `NS` entries on its parent zone (`com.`)
   - between authoritative name servers i.e. match with the `NS` records on the other servers.

   As Google Cloud DNS does not support using itself as a secondary, it will not add the existing name servers in its `NS` records, making it impossible to meet these requirements.